# How to verify the Hyperbolic Axiom from the Poincare model?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I was wondering how to verify that the Poincare model satisfies the hyperbolic axiom (i.e. that there are at least 2 lines through a point A parallel to line L?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tell us your definition of the "Poincare model" so we know the amount of rigor you need in your verification. In the disc model the lines are circular arcs perpendicular to the boundary and a picture is a convincing verification (for me).

Comment: The picture you added to the question is an answer. (Draw it for lines more general than diagonals.)

Comment: or provide an argument that we can assume that L is a diameter.